# Dynamic variable value

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to separate a log file and an error file that changes it name based on the customer name

```
$CS_NAME=""
$LOGFILE=-join ($LOGDIR,"\",$VER,"_",[ref]$CS_NAME,"_",$TODAY,".log")
$LOGERROR=-join ($LOGDIR,"\","ERROR-",$VER,"_",[ref]$CS_NAME,"_",$TODAY,".log")
```

Then I use a `switch` to write to each file

```
function output {
    $TYPE    = $args[0]
    $MESSAGE = $args[1]
    switch ($TYPE) {
        message {"message test "+$MESSAGE >> $LOGFILE}
        error {"error test "+$MESSAGE >> $LOGERROR}
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting the file names like this

```
COMPARE_System.Management.Automation.PSReference_2016184.log
ERROR-COMPARE_System.Management.Automation.PSReference_2016184.log
```

Comment: What is `[ref]$CS_NAME` supposed to do?

Comment: Why are you using `[ref]$CS_Name` instead of just `$CS_Name`?

Comment: Are you expecting `$LOGFILE` and `$LOGERROR` to expand `$CS_NAME` to its current value whenever you use those variables in your script? Because that's not this/variables works.

Comment: Hi Etan, yes, that what I want, because $CS_NAME will change along the script and I want it to catch always the last value

Comment: Doesn't work that way. Build `$LOGFILE` and `$LOGERROR` inside the function to have it pick up changes to `$CS_NAME` (e.g. `$LOGFILE = "${LOGDIR}\${VER}_${CS_NAME}_${TODAY}.log"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my tests the simpler way to do this is to substitute the [ref]$CS_NAME with an array $CS_NAME[$i].

With the array the value is available everywhere in the script and easier to change.

Answer (score 0):

not tested, but you could try something like this

```
$LOGDIR = 'c:'
$VER = '2.5'
$TODAY = Get-Date -f s

function LOGFILE {
    "$LOGDIR\$VER`_$CS_NAME`_$TODAY.log"
}

function LOGERROR {
    "$LOGDIR\ERROR-$VER`_$CS_NAME`_$TODAY.log"
}

function output {
    $TYPE    = $args[0]
    $MESSAGE = $args[1]
    switch ($TYPE) {
        message {"message test $MESSAGE" | Add-Content LOGFILE}
        error {"error test $MESSAGE" | Add-Content LOGERROR}
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The problem is that $CS_NAME is update several times during the execution. Like that I always have the first value.